# WPF: Window.Show() - doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have an application that on the first run will ask the user to choose configurations, and open a FirstRunWindow. After that, it launches the MainWindow.

Until now I had it wired up with events, and it worked perfectly. But I came to think that actually I don't need an event, and I tried to re-write the code, but I'm getting weird results.

1) If the check is made that there is no need to run the first window, it will load the main window fine. But if the First Window ran - the MainWindow.Show() won't work (i.e. the main window won't appear). I went over with debugger - no error is thrown, it seems to have been executed fine, but doesn't appear.

2) Changing Show to ShowDialog() doesn't solve it, and also throws an error when I call Application.Current.Shutdown().

3) Putting a MessageBox.Show() after the MainWindow.Show() works if the first window didn't appear, throws weird error if the first window appears (A very-very long stack with the final exception being "the uri prefix is not recognized" - but this seems completely unrelated, and all because of a MessageBox ???

I should also note that **ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"**. So there's no worries regarding having windows open or not.

Here is how the code looked like **before**, with events (again, this worked):

```
    public static event EventHandler ContinueMain;

    public void StartFlow()
    {

        // Check if this is the first run
        CheckFirstRun();

        // Hook up an event
        FirstRun.ContinueMain += FirstRun_ContinueMain;

    }

    private void FirstRun_ContinueMain(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContinueMain();
    }

    public void ContinueMain()
    {
        // Do Stuff
        DoStuff();

        // Show's Main Window
        ShowMain();
    }

    public void CheckFirstRun()
    {
        if (condition) 
            {
                firstRunWindow = new FirstRunWindow();
                firstRunWindow.Show();
                return;
            }

        ContinueMain();             
    }

    // Called when user clicks on Finish in last view in FirstRunWindow... 
    public void FirstRunFinish()
    {
        firstRunWindow.Close();
        ContinueMain?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty)     
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    { 
        //irrelevant    
    }

    public void ShowMain()
    {
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();

        mainWindow.Show();

    }
```

And here is how the code looks like now, without events but with bugs:

```
    public void StartFlow()
    {
        // Check if this is the first run
        CheckFirstRun();

        // Do Stuff
        DoStuff();

        // Show's Main Window
        ShowMain();
    }

    public void CheckFirstRun()
    {
        if (condition) 
            {
                firstRunWindow = new FirstRunWindow();
                firstRunWindow.ShowDialog(); // changed to ShowDialog, so that thread stops here and waits for the first window to close...
            }

    }

    public void FirstRunFinish()
    {
        firstRunWindow.Close();
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    { 
        //irrelevant    
    }

    public void ShowMain()
    {
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();

        mainWindow.Show();
        // MessageBox.Show("dbg: After mainWindow.Show()");

    }
```

WER / EventViewer show's the following errors:

```
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at System.Windows.Application.set_ShutdownMode(System.Windows.ShutdownMode)

Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(System.Exception, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   at JITBClient.App.Main()
```

here is the MessageBox Exception (same for Forms.MessageBox, and wpf MessageBox):

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

Adding `Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;` to the code seems to fix this, though I don't understand why the XAML version in App.xaml isn't enough... (as mentioned above, I do have `ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"` in App.xaml) If anyone can clarify if I did something wrong, or if it's a microsoft bug ???

Comment: So where in your code are you creating a WebRequest?

Comment: I'm not... this is caused by the MessageBox... weird